# Linux зависает насмерть

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

При использовании debian 10 в неопределённый момент( в случайном случае) зависает система. Причем напрочь... На клавиатуру не реагирует, пытался открыть терминал( ctrl + alt + f1), думал что оболочка виснет, но нет. Поставил убунту, тоже самое.

Железо

Мать китайская
Проц е5 1650
Видео gtx 550ti
16 оперативы

А самое странное то, что на другом жёстком диске стоит семерка, и на ней все работает идеально, не зависает, не тормозит.

Я понимаю, что нужно в логах смотреть, но я не могу понять в каких.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115186/discussion-on-question-by--linux--).